# Add space to the end on a widget

Tags: widgets, code

I have a widget that when stacked with another the out put from my widget to the next sit on top of each other. I tried echo `<br>` but that gives me a fatal error. Is there any other code to add to the end to increase the space?

```
 /**
 * Register the widget
 */
function wpspprofwid_load_widgets() {
    register_widget( 'WPS_PRO_Profile_Widget' );
}
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'wpspprofwid_load_widgets' );

/**
 * Profile Widget class.
 */
class WPS_PRO_Profile_Widget extends WP_Widget {

    /**
     * Widget setup.
     */
    public function __construct() {
        $widget_ops = array( 'description' => __('Add a custom Profile to your sidebar.') );
        parent::__construct( 'nav_menu1', __('WP Symposium PRO Profile'), $widget_ops );
    }

    // ********************** How to display Widget on Screen *******************************
    public function widget($args, $instance) {

        // THIS is where to ADD the code
        if ( ! is_user_logged_in() ) {
            echo '';
            return;
        }

        // Set Title
        $title = apply_filters( 'widget_title', $instance['title'] );

        // Display before widget code
        echo $before_widget;

        //Display Title
        if ( ! empty( $title ) )
            echo $args['before_title'] . $title . $args['after_title'];

        /* ========================= Avatar image start ====================================*/

        if($instance['avtar_size']!='')
        {

            echo do_shortcode('[wps-avatar size="'.$instance['avtar_size'].'"]');
        }
        /* ========================= Avatar image end ====================================*/
        // Do Shortcodes

        echo "<br>"; // space
        echo do_shortcode('[wps-friends-add-button]');
        echo "<br>"; // space

        // ====================== Menu Display ==================================

        //Set Menu title
        $mtitle = apply_filters( 'Menu Title', $instance['mtitle'] );

        //Display Title
        if ( ! empty( $mtitle ) )
            echo $args['before_mtitle'] . "<h3>$mtitle</h3>" . $args['after_mtitle'];

        // Get menu
        $nav_menu = ! empty( $instance['nav_menu'] ) ? wp_get_nav_menu_object( $instance['nav_menu'] ) : false;

        if($nav_menu != '')
        {
            wp_nav_menu( array( 'fallback_cb' => '', 'menu' => $nav_menu ) );
        }

        /* ========================= Friends shortcode start ====================================*/

        if($instance['friends_shortcode']=='on')
        {
            echo "<h3>My Friends</h3>";
            echo do_shortcode('[wps-friends size="35" count=5]');
        }

        /* ========================= Friends Page URL start ==================================*/

        echo '<p><a href="'.$instance ['friends_url'].'">'.$instance['fptitle'].'</a></p>';

        /* ========================= First Shortcode section start ===================================*/
        //Set Shortcode 1 title
        $sc1title = apply_filters( 'Shortcode 1 Title', $instance['sc1title'] );

        //Display Shortcode 1 title
        if ( ! empty( $sc1title ) )
            echo $args['before_sc1title'] . "<h3>$sc1title</h3>" . $args['after_sc1title'];

        //Do Shortcode 1
        echo do_shortcode($instance['sc1']);
        //echo "<br>";

        /* ========================= Second Shortcode section start ===============================*/

        //Set Shortcode 2 title
        $sc2title = apply_filters( 'Shortcode 2 Title', $instance['sc2title'] );

        //Display Shortcode 2 title
        if ( ! empty( $sc2title ) )
            echo $args['before_sc1title'] . "<h3>$sc2title</h3>" . $args['after_sc1title'];

        //Do Shortcode 2
        echo do_shortcode($instance['sc2']);
        //echo "<br>";

        /* ========================= Third Shortcode section start =====================*/

        //Set Shortcode 3 title
        $sc3title = apply_filters( 'Shortcode 3 Title', $instance['sc3title'] );

        //Display Shortcode 3 title
        if ( ! empty( $sc3title ) )
            echo $args['before_sc1title'] . "<h3>$sc3title</h3>" . $args['after_sc1title'];

        //Do Shortcode 3
        echo do_shortcode($instance['sc3']);
        //echo "<br>";

        /* ========================= Fourth Shortcode section start ==========================*/

        //Set Shortcode 4 title
        $sc4title = apply_filters( 'Shortcode 4 Title', $instance['sc4title'] );

        //Display Shortcode 4 title
        if ( ! empty( $sc4title ) )
            echo $args['before_sc1title'] . "<h3>$sc4title</h3>" . $args['after_sc1title'];

        //Do Shortcode 4
        echo do_shortcode($instance['sc4']);
        //echo "<br>";

        /* ========================= Fifth Shortcode section start ==========================*/

        //Set Shortcode 5 title
        $sc5title = apply_filters( 'Shortcode 5 Title', $instance['sc5title'] );

        //Display Shortcode 5 title
        if ( ! empty( $sc5title ) )
            echo $args['before_sc1title'] . "<h3>$sc5title</h3>" . $args['after_sc1title'];

        //Do Shortcode 5
        echo do_shortcode($instance['sc5']);
        //echo "<br>";

        /* ========================= Sixth Shortcode section start =============================*/

        //Set Shortcode 6 title
        $sc6title = apply_filters( 'Shortcode 6 Title', $instance['sc6title'] );

        //Display Shortcode 6 title
        if ( ! empty( $sc6title ) )
            echo $args['before_sc1title'] . "<h3>$sc6title</h3>" . $args['after_sc1title'];

        //Do Shortcode 6
        echo do_shortcode($instance['sc6']);

        echo $args['after_widget'];

        // Display after widget code
        echo $after_widget;
    }

    // Update the widget settings.
    public function update( $new_instance, $old_instance ) {
        $instance['title'] = strip_tags( stripslashes($new_instance['title']) );
        $instance['avtar_size'] =  strip_tags( stripslashes($new_instance['avtar_size']) );
        $instance['mtitle'] = strip_tags( stripslashes($new_instance['mtitle']) );
        $instance['nav_menu'] = (int) $new_instance['nav_menu'];
        $instance['friends_shortcode'] =  $new_instance['friends_shortcode'];
        $instance['fptitle'] = strip_tags( stripslashes($new_instance['fptitle']) );
        $instance['friends_url'] = strip_tags( stripslashes($new_instance['friends_url']) );
        $instance['sc1title'] = strip_tags( stripslashes($new_instance['sc1title']) );
        $instance['sc1'] = strip_tags( stripslashes($new_instance['sc1']) );
        $instance['sc2title'] = strip_tags( stripslashes($new_instance['sc2title']) );
        $instance['sc2'] = strip_tags( stripslashes($new_instance['sc2']) );
        $instance['sc3title'] = strip_tags( stripslashes($new_instance['sc3title']) );
        $instance['sc3'] = strip_tags( stripslashes($new_instance['sc3']) );
        $instance['sc4title'] = strip_tags( stripslashes($new_instance['sc4title']) );
        $instance['sc4'] = strip_tags( stripslashes($new_instance['sc4']) );
        $instance['sc5title'] = strip_tags( stripslashes($new_instance['sc5title']) );
        $instance['sc5'] = strip_tags( stripslashes($new_instance['sc5']) );
        $instance['sc6title'] = strip_tags( stripslashes($new_instance['sc6title']) );
        $instance['sc6'] = strip_tags( stripslashes($new_instance['sc6']) );
        return $instance;
    }

    // =============== Displays widget in Admin Panel

    public function form( $instance ) {
        $title = isset( $instance['title'] ) ? $instance['title'] : '';
        $avtar_size = isset( $instance['avtar_size'] ) ? $instance['avtar_size'] : '';
        $mtitle = isset( $instance['mtitle'] ) ? $instance['mtitle'] : '';
        $nav_menu = isset( $instance['nav_menu'] ) ? $instance['nav_menu'] : '';
        $friends_shortcode = isset( $instance['friends_shortcode'] ) ? $instance['friends_shortcode'] : '';
        $fptitle = isset( $instance['fptitle'] ) ? $instance['fptitle'] : '';
        $friends_url = isset( $instance['friends_url'] ) ? $instance['friends_url'] : '';
        $sc1title = isset( $instance['sc1title'] ) ? $instance['sc1title'] : '';
        $sc1 = isset( $instance['sc1'] ) ? $instance['sc1'] : '';
        $sc2title = isset( $instance['sc2title'] ) ? $instance['sc2title'] : '';
        $sc2 = isset( $instance['sc2'] ) ? $instance['sc2'] : '';
        $sc3title = isset( $instance['sc3title'] ) ? $instance['sc3title'] : '';
        $sc3 = isset( $instance['sc3'] ) ? $instance['sc3'] : '';
        $sc4title = isset( $instance['sc4title'] ) ? $instance['sc4title'] : '';
        $sc4 = isset( $instance['sc4'] ) ? $instance['sc4'] : '';
        $sc5title = isset( $instance['sc5title'] ) ? $instance['sc5title'] : '';
        $sc5 = isset( $instance['sc5'] ) ? $instance['sc5'] : '';
        $sc6title = isset( $instance['sc6title'] ) ? $instance['sc6title'] : '';
        $sc6 = isset( $instance['sc6'] ) ? $instance['sc6'] : '';

        // Get menus
        $menus = wp_get_nav_menus( array( 'orderby' => 'name' ) );

        // If no menus exists, direct the user to go and create some.
        if ( !$menus ) {
            echo '<p>'. sprintf( __('No menus have been created yet. <a href="%s">Create some</a>.'), admin_url('nav-menus.php') ) .'</p>';
            return;
        }
        // ============= Widget Selectio s and inputs
        ?>
        <p>
            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'title' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Title:', 'wpspprofwid' ); ?></label>
            <input type="text" class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('title'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('title'); ?>" value="<?php echo $title; ?>" />
        </p>
        <p>
        <div>Select Avatar Size Below:</div>
        <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'avtar_size' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Avatar Size: ' ); ?></label>
        <select id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'avtar_size' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('avtar_size'); ?>">
            <option value=""> - No Avatar - </option>
            <?php
                echo '<option value="200"'. selected( $avtar_size, '200', false ). '>200 x 200px</option>';
                echo '<option value="150"'. selected( $avtar_size, '150', false ). '>150 x 150px</option>';
                echo '<option value="100"'. selected( $avtar_size, '100', false ). '>100 x 100px</option>';
            ?>
        </select>
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'mtitle' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'User Menu Title:' ); ?></label>
            <input type="text" class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('mtitle'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('mtitle'); ?>" value="<?php echo $mtitle; ?>" />
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'nav_menu' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Set User Menu:' ); ?></label>
            <select id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'nav_menu' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('nav_menu'); ?>">
                <option value="">Select Menu</option>
                <?php
                    foreach ( $menus as $menu ) {
                        echo '<option value="' . $menu->term_id . '"'
                            . selected( $nav_menu, $menu->term_id, false )
                            . '>'. $menu->name . '</option>';
                    }
                ?>
            </select>
        </p>
        <p>
        <div>Check Box to Show Friends</div>
        <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'friends_shortcode' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Show Friends: ' ); ?></label>
        <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" <?php checked($friends_shortcode , 'on'); ?> id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('friends_shortcode'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('friends_shortcode'); ?>" />
        </p>
        <p>
        <div>Link for Friends Page - leave blank for no link</div>
        <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'fptitle' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Friend Page Label - ex. See All Friends' ); ?></label>
        <input type="text" class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('fptitle'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('fptitle'); ?>" value="<?php echo $fptitle; ?>" />
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'friends_url' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'URL to Friends Page:' ); ?></label>
            <input type="text" class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('friends_url'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('friends_url'); ?>" value="<?php echo $friends_url; ?>" />
        <p>Add Additional Shortcodes Below:</p>
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'sc1title' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Shortcode 1 Title:' ); ?></label>
            <input type="text" class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('sc1title'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('sc1title'); ?>" value="<?php echo $sc1title; ?>" />
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'sc1' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Shortcode 1:' ); ?></label>
            <textarea name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('sc1'); ?>" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('sc1'); ?>" class="widefat"><?php echo $sc1; ?></textarea>
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'sc1title' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Shortcode 2 Title:' ); ?></label>
            <input type="text" class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('sc2title'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('sc2title'); ?>" value="<?php echo $sc2title; ?>" />
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'sc2' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Shortcode 2:' ); ?></label>
            <textarea name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('sc2'); ?>" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('sc2'); ?>" class="widefat"><?php echo $sc2; ?></textarea>
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'sc3title' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Shortcode 3 Title:' ); ?></label>
            <input type="text" class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('sc3title'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('sc3title'); ?>" value="<?php echo $sc3title; ?>" />
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'sc3' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Shortcode 3:' ); ?></label>
            <textarea name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('sc3'); ?>" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('sc3'); ?>" class="widefat"><?php echo $sc3; ?></textarea>
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'sc4title' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Shortcode 4 Title:' ); ?></label>
            <input type="text" class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('sc4title'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('sc4title'); ?>" value="<?php echo $sc4title; ?>" />
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'sc4' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Shortcode 4:' ); ?></label>
            <textarea name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('sc4'); ?>" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('sc4'); ?>" class="widefat"><?php echo $sc4; ?></textarea>
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'sc5title' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Shortcode 5 Title:' ); ?></label>
            <input type="text" class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('sc5title'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('sc5title'); ?>" value="<?php echo $sc5title; ?>" />
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'sc5' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Shortcode 5:' ); ?></label>
            <textarea name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('sc5'); ?>" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('sc5'); ?>" class="widefat"><?php echo $sc5; ?></textarea>
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'sc6title' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Shortcode 6 Title:' ); ?></label>
            <input type="text" class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('sc6title'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('sc6title'); ?>" value="<?php echo $sc6title; ?>" />
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'sc6' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Shortcode 6:' ); ?></label>
            <textarea name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('sc6'); ?>" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('sc6'); ?>" class="widefat"><?php echo $sc6; ?></textarea>
        </p>
    <?php
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `style.css` add this:

```
.widget { margin-bottom: 20px; }
```

That should give all your widgets 20 pixels of spacing but only works when the widgets are stacked on top of eachother.

If you have multiple sidebars and only want this to happen on a single sidebar, add a more-specific selector i.e.

```
.my-special-sidebar .widget { margin-bottom: 20px; }
```

But that requires that you wrap your `dynamic_sidebar` call in a container with a class of `my-special-sidebar`.

Comment: Not using css file just php file

Comment: This is a style issue, though. And without any of your code it will be impossible to go any further.

Comment: Sorry I did not respond sooner.